# Best CMS for doing private site with Charting

Tags: php, mysql, web, content-management-system, charts

I'm really new to website development and for a project I need:

No public pages. All private.
Login+Password (Users, Admins)

Being able to upload XML-files from Android device
Parse this XML into something I can plot. Easy charting.
Admin users being able to read all sub-users uploads.

Doesn't have to look good.
No blog-post. Strictly XML-Charts.

I thought about using Wordpress, but I don't know if it's the best idea. I can code, but I don't have to much PHP + MySQL experience. Maybe there's something simpler?

Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can code then its really easy for you to do what you want with PHP/Mysql and parsing xml. PHP has great and easy charting capabilities out of the box.

If you add wordpress or another CMS into the mix then you may drown yourself to early. If you organise your code well, you'll be able to plug it into a CMS later.

Comment: Yes, you don't have to worry very much if you had bag organizing at the start. You can restart fresh and add the old code as "scripts" to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't need a CMS. You can manage with some php tutorials (google, tutorialized.com ...).
There is a library in php: SimplePHP, maybe it helps.

Wordpress is the easiest CMS out there, so if you need one, go with that.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You said all the pages in you project will be a private one. So, you dont want to go with the CMS or Opensources like wordpress...

It would be better you can code this project as custom one. Also there are much of open codes for XML-charts to implement it.

please see to this...
http://software.informer.com/getfree-xml-chart-generator/

Answer (score 0):

if you want have  alook at Contao.
Its easy to learn, free, safe and freshly programmed in PHP5  and its very easy to make a own template.
www.contao.org